# android application force closing

Tags: android, eclipse, android-intent, forceclose

I have a small menu with a button that says "about". When I press it, the app force closes. The logcat says there is no activity found to handle the intent but I am unsure why. It is declared in the manifest as follows

```
<activity
            android:name=".About"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.androidsleepmachine.gamble.About" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

The intent start in the code

```
   case R.id.About:
    Intent i = new Intent("com.androidsleepmachine.gamble.About");
    startActivity(i);
    break;
```

Logcat file

05-08 23:13:19.258: E/AndroidRuntime(15746): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-08 23:13:19.258: E/AndroidRuntime(15746): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=com.androidsleepmachine.gamble.About }
05-08 23:13:19.258: E/AndroidRuntime(15746):    at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1545)
05-08 23:13:19.258: E/AndroidRuntime(15746):    at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1416)
05-08 23:13:19.258: E/AndroidRuntime(15746):    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3389)
05-08 23:13:19.258: E/AndroidRuntime(15746):    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3350)
05-08 23:13:19.258: E/AndroidRuntime(15746):    at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3562)
05-08 23:13:19.258: E/AndroidRuntime(15746):    at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3528)
05-08 23:13:19.258: E/AndroidRuntime(15746):    at com.androidsleepmachine.gamble.Home.onOptionsItemSelected(Home.java:83)
05-08 23:13:19.258: E/AndroidRuntime(15746):    at android.app.Activity.onMenuItemSelected(Activity.java:2566)
05-08 23:13:19.258: E/AndroidRuntime(15746):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.onMenuItemSelected(PhoneWindow.java:978)
05-08 23:13:19.258: E/AndroidRuntime(15746):    at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder.java:735)
05-08 23:13:19.258: E/AndroidRuntime(15746):    at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:149)
05-08 23:13:19.258: E/AndroidRuntime(15746):    at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:874)
05-08 23:13:19.258: E/AndroidRuntime(15746):    at   com.android.internal.view.menu.ListMenuPresenter.onItemClick(ListMenuPresenter.java:166)

Comment: Please post the error logs

Comment: are you sure, About class is in com.androidsleepmachine.gamble package ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this,

```
    Intent i = new Intent(this,About.class);
// you may need to end this current activity if you dont want to use it anymore, just add `flags` to the intent 
startActivity(i);
```

in your manifest `android:name=` hit `control` and `space` at same time and choose your class from there to avoid any issues regarding pointing to your class.

Comment: Both of those worked to fix the issue. Thank you and thank you all for taking the time to reply.

Answer (score 0):

change the name like.

```
<activity
        android:name="com.androidsleepmachine.gamble.About"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Comment: Still force closes when using your fix

Comment: Give your package name exactly what you created, without changing capital letters.

Comment: package com.androidsleepmachine.gamble; The reason it shows other places as androidsleepsounds is because I had to change the name of the app due to another app maker owning sleep and machine in the use of a title.

Answer (score 0):

Logs shows the problem clearly.

Your are trying to start `Activity` of name `com.AndroidSleepSounds.gamble.About`

```
 com.AndroidSleepSounds.gamble.About
```

But, it is not in the Manifest .

```
 android:name="com.androidsleepmachine.gamble.About"
```

This is different class name . change it to

```
android:name="com.AndroidSleepSounds.gamble.About"
```

Comment: Just made that change and it still force closes.